# macOS Sonoma: magnetic effect on windows has disappeared

Tags: macos, windows, desktop, sonoma

I have noticed that the magnetic effect between windows in macOS Sonoma has disappeared. This was an easy way to precisely arrange windows and "glue" them together on the desktop.

Does anyone know how to reinstate this useful feature?

Comment: You'll probably have to report it as a bug & see if it gets fixed in a later version. It never used to have a switch, it just appeared in maybe Mojave… or the Sierras which I skipped.

Comment: What is the magnetic effect?

Comment: @Thinkr It's two windows being attracted magnetically to one another when they are near. It was very handy in previous versions of macOS, but it has disappeared in Sonoma.

Comment: @AgentSmith Oh. I never noticed this feature before. What I can do in Sonoma, is bring a window close to another one (touching) and try to make that window go on top of the other one. There should be a slight resistance.

Comment: @Thinkr Then you are lucky, because the “slight resistance” you refer to is exactly what I mean. Except this behavior does not occur on my machine…

Comment: @AgentSmith Oh. I guess this might be due to a setting you have changed since updating (or just before). I also noticed that it only works if you bring them ***slowly*** together. Maybe you're doing it too fast?

Comment: @Thinkr No, I do it slowly. It just disappeared with Sonoma.

Comment: @AgentSmith Oh. Do you remember changing a setting related to that recently?

Comment: @Thinkr No, nothing.

Comment: Sonoma 14.1 update: it appears that the magnetic effect works when dragging a window's border near another window's border, but still not when dragging an entire window.